# How to use AutoMapper to convert Child Object list to either list of strings or list of Guids

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, nested-lists

I have tried using a custom converted

`CreateMap<ChildB, string>().ConvertUsing(src => src.Name);`

But I run into the scenario when I want to sometimes get the string like above or sometimes I want to just get the Guid:
`CreateMap<ChildB, Guid>().ConvertUsing(src => src.Id);`

It seems to throw and error as it always converts the Name.  The Objects are like this:

```
public class ParentA
{
 public Guid Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public ICollection<ChildB>? {get;set;}
 ...
}

public class ChildB
{
 public Guid Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 ...
}
public class ParentADTO1
{
 public Guid Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public ICollection<string> ChildNames{get;set;}
 ...
}
public class ParentADTO2
{
 public Guid Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public ICollection<Guid> ChildIds {get;set;}
 ...
}
```

So the question is, can I use the `CreateMap` function like so:

```
CreateMap<ParentA,ParentADTO1>()
  ...
 .ForMember(ent => ent.ChildNames, opt => opt.MapFrom(???))

CreateMap<ParentA,ParentADTO2>()
  ...
 .ForMember(ent => ent.ChildIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(???))
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up the mapping configuration like this (I suppose the property is named `Children`):

```
public class ParentA
{
 public Guid Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public ICollection<ChildB> Children {get;set;}
 // ...
}
```

---

```
CreateMap<ParentA,ParentADTO1>()
  // ...
 .ForMember(ent => ent.ChildNames, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Children.Select(y => y.Name).ToArray()))

CreateMap<ParentA,ParentADTO2>()
  // ...
 .ForMember(ent => ent.ChildIds, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Children.Select(y => y.Id).ToArray()))
```

Comment: Well - That's awesome!  Thank you so much for such a quick response

Answer (score 1):

@Markus answer is certainly valid and is an excellent solution.  FWIW, here is another approach you could by using the built-in [AutoMapper's Flattening pattern](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html).  Simply add a Get[PropertyName] method to the source class to combine the child objects in whatever way you want it.  Here is the complete example:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public ICollection<string> GetChildNames()
    {
        return Children.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
    }

    public ICollection<Guid> GetChildIds()
    {
        return Children.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParentWithChildNames
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> ChildNames { get; set; }
}
public class ParentWithChildIds
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Guid> ChildIds { get; set; }
}

//No need to map the member, you could use Get[PropertyName] approach to automatically map it
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Parent, ParentWithChildIds>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Parent, ParentWithChildNames>();
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Comment: That's cool - so AutoMapper knows due to NamingConvention that the "Get" function should be used to assign that field.  I assume both will have to be either ICollection/IEnumerable or whatever for the convention to work?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, the return type of "Get" method must be compatible with the property type.